devtools install http error for baseballr
I can install baseballr with the install.packages, but statcast data doesn't work in this because of bat tracking data being added. The devtools fix they proposed I cannot get to work. This is the error I get when I run their fix:
> devtools::install_github(repo = "BillPetti/baseballr")
Using GitHub PAT from the git credential store.
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 55/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2024-07-30 14:59:23 UTC


What if you try devtools::install_github(repo = "BillPetti/baseballr", auth_token=NULL). It seems you may have set up a personal access token for github that has now expired which is making the login fail

@MrFlick same error just without the "Using GitHub PAT from the git credential store."

It still says bad credentials? I can't replicate. If I run devtools::install_github(repo = "BillPetti/baseballr", auth_token = NULL) it installs version 1.6.0 of the package. Rest with devtools 2.4.5 and R 4.3.3. If I run devtools::install_github(repo = "BillPetti/baseballr", auth_token = "bad") I get the "Bad credentials" error.

@MrFlick your fix worked. This was messing it up: Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")
[1] "your_github_pat" Once i unset it it worked
